# Ord in implicit definition, error with guards

Tags: haskell

I'm getting following error

```
Prelude> abs n | n>=0 = n+100 | otherwise =n
Prelude> abs 10
110
Prelude> abs -1

<interactive>:44:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (t -> t)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t. (Ord t, Num (t -> t), Num t) => t -> t
```

1. Why there is `Ord` in implicit type definition?
2. What the error is saying?
3. what is wrong in the definition?

Comment: The fix is to put `-1` in brackets, e.g. `abs (-1)`, this is due to haskell's parsing, someone else can explain better than I can the other questions.

Comment: `abs -1` to Haskell looks like `abs - 1`, as if `abs` were a number, this is the quirk of Haskell's parsing @Zpalmtree was talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `abs -1` or `x -1` Haskell parse `-` as binary operator. So it complains that `abs` (which is a function) is not a number.  As  Zpalmtree said, you need to write `abs (-1)`.